# An error occurred while executing the command definition

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The following method is throwing the exception (An error occurred while executing the command definition)

```
public static List<NameAndValue> GetCodes(SearchTextRequest searchTextRequest)
{

    using (var db = new ToolsCommonEntities())
    {
        if (searchTextRequest != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTextRequest.SearchText))
        {
            return db.Codes.Where(x => x.Code.Contains(searchTextRequest.SearchText)).Select(x => new NameAndValue { Name = x.Code, Value = x.CodeType }).Distinct().ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return db.Codes.Select(x => new NameAndValue { Name = x.Code, Value = x.CodeType }).Distinct().ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

This method was able to get the values from Codes table perfectly fine. But, when I started to populate the values in 'Codes' table using a c# service, the above error started to occur.

**Question:**

How to read value from the 'Codes' table when another service is populating values in it? Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: There's likely to be an inner exception that gives more detail - can you provide that?

Comment: I could not find any information in the inner exception.. it was empty